# How do I remove a piece of software from auto-starting when I reboot my Mac? 

Tags: macos, mac, boot

How do I edit my startup programs for Mac OS X?

In particular, I have this "Hotspot Shield" program I installed that is starting up every time I reboot my computer. I want to remove it from auto-startup.